# Application Closed Graph Theorem to Cauchy problem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider $E:=C^0([a,b])\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $F:=C^n([a,b])$ equipped with the product norms.
Consider 
$$ u^{(n)}+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}a_i(t)u^{(i)}=f
$$
with $$u(t_0)=w_1,\dots,u^{(n-1)}(t_0)=w_n \\
a_i\in C^0([a,b]),w_i\in\mathbb{R},t_0\in [a,b]$$ Then, let $T:E\to F$, defined by $$T(f,w)=u $$ where $u$ is the unique solution of the Cauchy problem.

My goal is to prove that $T$ is linear and bounded.

For what concerns the boundedness, I know that I have to apply the Closed Graph Theorem, since $E$ and $F$ are Banach. However, I can't prove any of the two thesis.
Any idea?

Comment: $T$ is linear, and "where $u$ is the unique solution of the Cauchy problem" bijective. Does that give you an idea?

Comment: This doesn't give me any idea :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the map $D\colon F\to E$ given by

$$D(u) = \left(u^{(n)} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i\cdot u^{(i)}, (u^{(i)}(t_0))\right).$$

It is elementary to verify that $D$ is continuous, and then you can note that $D = T^{-1}$ to conclude.

Alternatively, if you want to directly use the closed graph theorem, consider sequences $\bigl((f_k,w_k)\bigr)$ and $(u_k)$ with $u_k = T(f_k,w_k)$ such that $(f_k,w_k) \to (f,w)$, and $u_k\to u$. Then

$$u^{(i)}(t_0) = \lim_{k\to\infty} u_k^{(i)}(t_0) = \lim_{k\to\infty} w_k^i = w^i$$

for $0 \leqslant i < n$ and

$$u^{(n)} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i\cdot u^{(i)} = \lim_{k\to\infty} u_k^{(n)} + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i\cdot u_k^{(i)} = \lim_{k\to\infty} f_k = f,$$

so $u = T(f,w)$, which shows that the graph of $T$ is closed.